# Sync-Async Blocking, Non-Blocking I/O

Tags: node.js, blocking, nonblocking

The question is about the explanation of these terms.
Are these true or false:

1. Blocking I/O == Sync Non-Blocking I/O ?
2. Non-Blocking I/O == Async Non-Blocking I/O == Async Blocking I/O?

I'm confused because of this explanation of [Blocking vs Non-Blocking](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/):

> All of the I/O methods in the Node.js standard library provide
>   asynchronous versions, which are non-blocking, and accept callback
>   functions

according to this, there are `Sync Non-Blocking` and `Async Non-Blocking`
Would you tell the difference between `(Non-Blocking || Sync Non-Blocking)` and `Async Non-Blocking`?

Answer (score 0):

there are no "sync non-blocking" function. The most important sentence in the linked article is:

> Blocking methods execute synchronously and non-blocking methods execute asynchronously.

that is all there is to say.

I/O could be many things like user input or reading from a file. User input is the best way to describe it:

A syncronous function would stop all execution of any other code, waiting for user input...

pseudocode:

```
while(clicked==false){
    clicked=check_for_user_click()
}
do_something_with_input()
do_everything_else()
```

here do_something_else would only run after the user clicked.

asyncronous function would not stop at all.

pseudocode:

```
while(clicked==false){
    clicked=check_for_user_click()
    do_everything_else()
}
do_something_with_input()
```

here do_everything_else() will be called in between every check for user input.